# TwinCat How To Initialize Functionblock with Reference to Global Variable

Tags: plc, twincat, codesys

Hello StackOverflow Community,

i have another question regarding the TwinCat/Beckhoff/Codesys Programming Language, maybe someone is able to help me with this problem.

Here is the Problem:
I want to initalize a functionblock with a reference to some variable. (In this example a simple bool).
Hereby i want to make use of the FB_Init Method.

The Functionblock itself looks something like this:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK PUBLIC FB_Ref
VAR
    reftoBool : REFERENCE TO BOOL;
END_VAR
```

The FB_Init Method looks something like this:

```
METHOD FB_init : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    bInitRetains : BOOL := FALSE;
    bInCopyCode : BOOL := FALSE;
    reftoBoolIn : REFERENCE TO BOOL;
END_VAR



reftoBool := reftoBoolIn;
```

The problem is that i can't get the code to work.. i don't know what im doing wrong.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is it that's not working? Is it not compiling? Do you get a runtime error? Without more details you're forcing anyone that might eventually help you to write an example him/herself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use REF= in the body of FB_init, like so:

```
reftoBool REF= reftoBoolIn;
```

See documentation here:
https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/136301707.html

Comment: Thank you, thats the Solution! I already knew about the syntax but somehow didn't really know how to use it. Now its working perfectly. I have a additional question: if i use the var_in_out variables of functionblocks does it allocate memory ? Or is it internally using pointers/references ?

Comment: It does allocate memory, but only for a reference to the variable type you are passing in. So this is a reference that you are passing, without having to go through additional reference or pointer syntax.